# imap_open: Can't open stream

Tags: php, imap, ssl, imap-open

I'm trying to use imap_open() for my FatCow email account. Here's my code:

```
$mbox = imap_open("{imap.fatcow.com:143}", "account@domain.com", "password");
```

Here's what I receive:

> Warning: imap_open() [function.imap-open]: Couldn't open stream {imap.fatcow.com:143} in /home/alfatcom/public_html/test.php on line 2

Maybe the reason is that FatCow uses STARTTLS? Anyway, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: did u try {imap.fatcow.com:143}INBOX ?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-open.php

Comment: also:   {imap.fatcow.com:143/tls}INBOX

Comment: @Arfeen, just did: nothing changed

Comment: @vlzvl, with {imap.fatcow.com:143/tls}INBOX - same thing

Comment: @Sergey, I know about this article, I'm actually basing my code on Example #2 from it.

Comment: I've always tried to open "gmail / google apps email" with "ssl" and it works.

Comment: try this as last resort:   {imap.fatcow.com:143/imap/tls/novalidate-cert}INBOX

Comment: @vlzvl, unfortunately, it didn't work, even warning is still "Couldn't open stream ..."

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was `{domain:110/pop3/novalidate-cert}INBOX` that helped me in fixing both the CLOSED IMAP connection broken (server response) and Certificate failure for domain.

Confirm your ports and also whether you have ssl enabled using

```
openssl s_client -crlf -connect your-domain-name:port-number
```